# how can we make http request from host server to endpoint inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js13, docker-container, dockerode

I want to make http request from server running on localhost currently to api endpoint inside running container. I can't use portmapping as I am creating multiple containers one container per request.

this is how my code looks
I am using dockerode create,run,stop and delete container for each request.
Container creation and run happens successfully but axios request gets timed out.
Is there any solution for this?

```
 const data = await request.json();
    const { language, program, inputs } = data;
    const docker = new Docker();
    const containerId = v4();
    // 1. I am trying to spin new container using dockerode on each request
    const container = await docker.createContainer({
      Image: "project-name",
      name: containerId,
    });
    await container.start();
    const containerInfo = await container.inspect();
    const ipAddress = containerInfo.NetworkSettings.IPAddress;
    const containerUrl = `http://${ipAdress}/api/run`;
    // 2 .Send code as input to that container's api/run endpoint (Where compiler logic is)

    const response = await axios.post(containerUrl, data);
    // 3. Then stop and remove after getting output
    await container.stop();
    await container.remove();
```

Comment: What is it about your setup that requires a new instance for every connection? (Rather than, say, serving connections from a pool of instances like usual.)

Comment: My purpose of running new container on each request is to compile user's code in sandboxed(isolated) environment @Ouroborus

Answer (score 0):

Except in one very specific host setup, you can't access the container-private IP addresses.  You need to publish a port and you need to access the container through its published port.  However, you don't have to pick a port yourself; if you don't assign a port then Docker will choose an unused port on its own.  (In `docker run` syntax, this is equivalent to `docker run -p 12345` with only a container port number and nothing else.)

```js
docker.createContainer({
  Image: "project-name",
  Name: containerId,
  HostConfig: {
    PortBindings: {
      "80/tcp": [ {} ]
    }
  }
});
```

Now when you inspect the container, the `PortBindings` value will be filled in.

```js
const containerInfo = await container.inspect();
const host = 'localhost'; // but see below
const port = containerInfo.HostConfig.PortBindings['80/tcp'][0].HostPort;
const containerUrl = `http://${host}:${port}/api/run`;
```

The `host` value is harder to determine programmatically.  If your application is running on plain Docker on a native-Linux host, or on Docker Desktop, then `localhost` will be right.  If this application itself is running inside a container with access to the host's Docker socket, you will need `host.docker.internal` or a similar value.  I generally use a Minikube VM in my day job, and its `minikube ip` address is what I need.  You can also set up to use a remote Docker daemon and the host name will be something else entirely.

As a comment suggests, I might rethink this approach.  Launching a container per request is actually kind of expensive, there are a lot of lifecycle issues to think about (what happens to the container if the main process creashes), and launching containers implies unrestricted root-level access to the host.  I also hinted at some environment-specific differences in the previous paragraph, and this code won't run at all in non-Docker container environments like Kubernetes.  If you can set up a single long-running server and make HTTP requests to that, it will be much more maintainable (and much easier to actually run).

Comment: I am pretty new with containers and stuff like this. 
As you said port will be dynamically added. But If we deploy this will the same url with host defined as localhost works? @David Maze

Comment: is there no way we can send input and capture output from api endpoint inside running container

Comment: The best practice will be what @Ouroborus suggested in their comment on the question: start one long-running instance of the server container and make normal HTTP requests to it, don't use the Docker API at all.

Comment: My purpose of running new container on each request is to compile user's code in sandboxed(isolated) environment